What would be the effect of a nuclear explosion occurring on a beach or close to the surf?
So nuclear explosions in water tend to have different effects as water is denser than air and incompressible(and if I'm not mistaken it tends to absorb a significant amount of blast energy). But I have not found any information about nuclear tests directly on the surf or extremely close to shoreline. Now I imagine that if, say, a massive 50 megaton warhead detonated underwater in a city harbor within 500 feet of the shore, a portion of the fireball would spread onto land and you would have some massive waves generated. But it would also vaporize much of the water in the harbor. But would that create a deluge of water washing onto the shore as well? It would be useful to have access to a simulator but that tends to involve supercomputers.

My recollection is that some nuclear weapon tests were conducted on very small islands, which would probably include the effects you want.

@StephenG-HelpUkraine my recollection is that these islands no longer exist, which inadvertedly answers the question as "the beach would move inwards by the difference between the fireball diameter and the distance of the detonation to the shore"

It's worth mentioning that nobody has 50Mton warheads. The US uses 250kton warheads and Russia seems to be going with 1Mton devices. At least that's the documented range of devices in active arsenals. These are plenty powerful enough to achieve the necessary military effects.

@FlatterMann - the B83 is over 1Mton and is in cthe current stockpile.

@JonCuster I stand corrected.

@FlatterMann I believe Russia does have 20MT warheads in its stockpile. And while nobody had a 50MT warhead currently, there is no reason why one could not be built(using the Tsar bomba design).

@MrX The Russians like to make unsubstantiated claims, so I kind of doubt that, especially since such a weapon has no conceivable military use. Smaller and lighter is, for purposes of delivery, better.

@FlatterMann The R-36 missile, which is still in service, is capable of carrying a large warhead. There was a variant which is no longer currently in service which carried a single 20MT warhead. So I would say it isn't too farfetched that some of those are still lying around in storage somewhere. The main use of them would be to destroy hardened targets like Cheyenne Mountain Complex.

@MrX I stand corrected, again.
